# How to Bind mulitple dropdownlist from database using MVC via Ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have multiple dropdownlist, i want to bind the data on page load, I'm working on MVC 4. In single stored procedure, i'm selecting data from different table. Each select for one dropdownlist.
here i assigning value to list, i want to return everything in a single list to controller. herewith i have given single dropdown as a sample.

```
public class SampleClass1
{

     public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Cr_PId { get; set; }
    public string Cr_cId { get; set; }
    public string Res { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public IList<ApplicationMaster> lstappmas { get; set; }
}

  public class ApplicationMaster
{
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

}
         public List<CrimsDetailModel> GetCrimsDetails()
    {
        List<CrimsDetailModel> lstcrimsdtls = new List<CrimsDetailModel>();
        List<ApplicationMaster> lstappdtls = new List<ApplicationMaster>();
        DataSet dscrmodel = new DataSet();
        Hashtable htcrmodel = new Hashtable();
        dscrmodel = DataProxy.FetchDataSet("GetCrimDetails");
        dscrmodel.Tables[0].TableName = "CRdetails";
        dscrmodel.Tables[1].TableName = "ApplicatonMaster";

        try
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dscrmodel.Tables["CRdetails"].Rows)
            {
                CrimsDetailModel objcrmodel = new CrimsDetailModel();
                objcrmodel.ID = dr["CR_PaId"].ToString();
                objcrmodel.Cr_PId = dr["CR_PId"].ToString();
                objcrmodel.Cr_cId = dr["CRIMS_CId"].ToString();
                objcrmodel.Res = dr["Res"].ToString();
                objcrmodel.Desc = dr["Desc"].ToString();

                lstcrimsdtls.Add(objcrmodel);
              }
           foreach (DataRow dr in dscrmodel.Tables["Appdetails"].Rows)
            {
                ApplicationMaster objapp = new ApplicationMaster();
                objapp.ApplicationId = dr["ApplicationId"].ToString();
                objapp.ApplicationName = dr["ApplicationName"].ToString();

                lstappdtls.Add(objapp);
            }
       return lstcrimsdtls;
```

}

When i assign

Answer (score 1):

You are using MVC (Model-View-Controller). You should assign your data to the Model class in the Controller. You can display your Model in a View. [Codeproject - Learn MVC step by step](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866143/Learn-MVC-step-by-step-in-days-Day)

Do I haz teh codez? For sure! :>

First, you create a ViewModel that holds the data to be displayed. It also has a getter to convert the possible options into the collection of `SelectListItem` required by Razor.

```
 public class ContainsADropdownViewModel {

    public CrimsDetailModel Selected { get; set; }

    // to be read in controller
    public IEnumerable<CrimsDetailModel> RawOptions { get; set; }

    // generate SelectListItems to be used with DropDownListFor()
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Options { get { 
        foreach (var detail in RawOptions) {
            yield return new SelectListItem {
                Value = detail.ID, // something unique
                Text =  detail.Desc, // shown to User
                Selected = detail == Selected // stays selected after roundtrip
            };
        }
    }}
}
```

Then you create a Controller containing two Actions, one to display the page initially `[HttpGet]` and one to handle the postback of the form `[HttpPost]`.

The GET action should return a strongly typed view, using the ViewModel. Here is the place to read from the database!

```
public class MyDropdownTestController : Controller {

    // GET MyDropdownTest/Index
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        var vm = new ContainsADropdownViewModel();
        vm.RawOptions = GetCrimsDetails(); // read from backend
        return View("Index", vm);
    }

    // POST MyDropdownTest/Index
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ContainsADropdownViewModel vm) {
        var optionChosenByUser = vm.Selected;
        // process form, send HTTP 200 OK or whatever
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

The View "Index" displays the dropdown and submits the filled out ViewModel to the post action specified in `Html.BeginForm`.

```
// Razor View in Views\MyDropdownTest\Index.cshtml
@model ContainsADropdownViewModel 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MyDropdownTest", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @* render dropdown; bind selected value to Model.Selected *@
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Selected, Model.Options)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Comment: i want  lstcrimsdtls and lstappdtls in a single list

Comment: Then tune the method that generates the `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to include options from both raw lists. Just be careful that `SelectListItem.Value` is unique.

Comment: sorry i have miscommunication, i want a list which contains lstcrimsdtls and lstappdtls. lstappdtls used for drop down, lstcrimsdtls for the textboxes and pages.

Comment: I am not sure if I unterstand your requirements, but maybe you can split the `GetCrimsDetails()` method into two, one returning the lstcrimsdtls and one returning the lstappdtls. Then use only the lstappdtls as RawData for the dropdown.